# Scala, find if value is between two integers

Tags: scala

I have an array of values

```
guests [1,2G,5G,5,6,8lalala,74,2zooo,555,654,22,21,19,4,5,2,10,11]
```

I need to find if '6' is between **0 and 15**

I have tried the following:

```
if(Math.min(0, guests.toInt) == Math.max(guests.toInt, 15)) return xxxxxx
```

I'm getting nothing, it seems as though my if statemented is skipped all together

*Please note, i don't want to return a Boolean*

Comment: What does  the array had to do with the question? What does play has to do with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition:

```
Math.min(0, guests.toInt) == Math.max(guests.toInt, 15)
```

will always fail.

For `i` between 0 and 15, `Math.min(0, i)` will always return 0.

For `i` between 0 and 15, `Math.max(i, 15)` will always return 15.

So you will compare `0 == 15`.

For ints below 0 or above 15 you will have:

`less than 0 == 15`

or

`0 == more than 15`

What you actually wanted to write is:

```
val i = guests.toInt
if (0 <= i && i <= 15) xxxxxx
else { some other value }
```